# Apparent no-op in Rust assembly output?

Tags: assembly, rust, bit-manipulation, x86-64

I was studying the x86_64 assembly for the following function:

```rust
/// Returns the greatest power of two less than or equal to `self`, or 0 otherwise.
pub const fn prev_power_of_two(n: u64) -> u64 {
    // n = 0 gives highest_bit_set_idx = 0.
    let highest_bit_set_idx = 63 - (n|1).leading_zeros();
    // Binary AND of highest bit with n is a no-op, except zero gets wiped.
    (1 << highest_bit_set_idx) & n
}
```

When compiling with `-C opt=level=3` we get [the following assembly](https://rust.godbolt.org/z/xzxaca) on nightly and 1.50.0:

```
example::prev_power_of_two:
        mov     rax, rdi
        or      rax, 1
        bsr     rcx, rax
        xor     ecx, 63
        xor     cl, 63
        mov     eax, 1
        shl     rax, cl
        and     rax, rdi
        ret
```

Everything seems good, except I can't explain these two instructions:

```
    xor     ecx, 63
    xor     cl, 63
```

As far as I can see, these are a no-op. Why are they generated?

Comment: It's a missed optimization. The `xor ecx, 63` comes from the fact that `bsr` gives an index not a count. The second `xor cl, 63` comes from the `63 - x`.

Comment: @Jester If I isolate `highest_bit_set_idx` to its own function you can see that the `xor` doesn't appear at all after the `bsr` (but reappears when inlined): https://rust.godbolt.org/z/EMbMb4 .

Comment: It comes back if you make your return type `u8` though. Using it in the shift presumably triggers that same conversion.

Comment: Yuck; if LLVM was smarter it would see `xor eax,eax` / `bsr rdi,rdi` (find MSB) / `bts rax, rdi` (set it in a zeroed reg) / ret.  (If RDI=0, BSR will leave RDI=0, although this behaviour is unfortunately only documented for AMD; Intel just does it without documenting.  OR with 1 avoids that at fairly low cost.) Or use `lzcnt` and rotate a `1` to the right, to optimize for AMD where `bsr` is slow.  Anyway, IDK if there's much hope of getting LLVM or GCC to emit either of those sequences.

Comment: If you use `-C target-cpu=native` to enable `lzcnt`, then `let c = 64 - n.leading_zeros(); (n >> (c & 63)) << (c & 63)` gives decent code. At assembly level it would also work fine with `bsr` since it doesn't matter what the result for 0 is.

Comment: You can enable a few extra unstable optimisations with `-Z mir-opt-level=3` on Nightly, although they don't seem to help in this case.

Answer (score 1):

This problem has been fixed. Rust nightly no longer generates these `xor` instructions.

See [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/P89W7aYa4)